# typescript how to add nested types when extending

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have this type.

```
type Deposit {
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
}

type Nice {
   num: number;
   deposit: Deposit;
}
```

Now, I use `Nice`, but I need to somehow extend it and I want its `deposit` to be including more fields. In the end, like this:

```
type Deposit {
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
    num3: string;
    num4: string;
}

type Nice {
   num: number;
   deposit: Deposit;
}
```

But, I can't change `Deposit` or `Nice` types since they come from the library.

Comment: What does *since they come from the library.* mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom child type using the `extends` keyword and just place it in a common `types.ts` file, then import the type from there instead of importing it from the library directly.

```
// src/types.ts

import { Deposit as DepositBase, Nice as NiceBase } from 'some-lib';

export interface Deposit extends DepositBase {
  num3: string;
  num4: string;
}

export interface Nice extends NiceBase {
  deposit: Deposit;
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
// src/some-lib-wrapper.ts

import * as someLib from 'some-lib';
import { Deposit, Nice } from './types'; // our extended types

// you can "re-type" the library functions in this wrapper module
// to use our custom extended types
export function makeDeposit(nice: Nice): Deposit {
  /* call someLib.makeDeposit here... */
}
```

```
// src/index.ts

import { makeDeposit } from './some-lib-wrapper'; // use the wrapped version
                                                  // with our extended types
import { Deposit, Nice } from './types';

// use your custom wrapped functions & types
makeDeposit(...);
```

Comment: Presuming this "library" exposes these types for a reason this doesn't seem like a great idea.

Comment: it exposes these types , yes. Why is it not a good idea ?

Comment: Assuming Nika is just adding some additional meta information, this is a perfectly normal use-case. Another potential approach would be to wrap the library's type and add your "extended" properties as extra keys, something like `interface DepositExtended { deposit: Deposit; extra: { num3: string; num4: string } }`, but I think as long as the extended types are purely additive (they're not removing/overwriting library types with more strict types) it should be safe to use `extends` as shown above.

Comment: Because @NikaKurashvili you could simply make breaking changes to the types, thus making your library not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper type for extending existing property:

```js
type Deposit = {
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
}

type Nice = {
    num: number;
    deposit: Deposit;
}

type ExtendProp<Obj, Prop, NewValue> = {
    [P in keyof Obj]: P extends Prop ? Obj[P] & NewValue : Obj[P]
}

type Result = ExtendProp<Nice, 'deposit', { foo: 'bar' }> // { deposit: Deposit & { foo: 'bar';  };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhYHsDOBLYUC8UDeBYAUFEVAHYCuAtgIwBcplARhAE4DcBx9FATHeRUzYEAvgQKhIUAHIoAxtCx5Cxfn0Yt2yogBN4yNHTiJUwTaPzjw0AKIAPYBBLaACswRgAPAHkGAKwA0UK7ugVIQAO4AagCGADZkEAB8mDgcxADazlAoJFAA1hAgCABmUD6%20ALp0WRD2jtpIQW5gUAD8ZX6ZFVAAZNIRMfHQdOVdImL4EjZ1ThDakSyoCCQeRgjAKEhh4cFgSMlYdg5Oux4y8oEA5LrGaJeBaxtbEbv7E1NQAEoQSGSx6IcZi5mmc5BArjd9MB7jgoMUEAg6JcGNFmJcoMJkgB6LGwyEmQx6Ey9WHwxFQZGoy6sIjCTQEIA)